# How can I set a unique cookie for each website domain

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

Having a problem with conflicting cookies when I switch domains. How can I set a unique cookie for each website domain with:

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    cookie: {
        name: 'tab_cookie',
        expires: 7,
    },
    fx: { 
        opacity: 'toggle', 
        duration: 'fast'
    }
});
```

If possible I would like this to work in the local development environment using localhost. E.g: http://localhost/cms1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `domain` and `path` in the `cookie` option, e.g.

```
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    cookie: {
        domain: 'localhost',
        path: '/',
        name: 'tab_cookie',
        expires: 7,
    },
    ...
});
```

Take a look at the [documentation of the cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for more options you can set.